# Builders page disappeared from Eclipse project properties

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, android-ndk

I do not know what happened to my Eclipse (Helios) with latest Android SDK and latest Sequoyah plugins. Suddenly, I do not see my the "Builders" page in Project properties - not for a single project in my workspace.

How can I restore this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which perspective you are in at the moment (upper right corner). A perspective can suppress UI contributions (such as property pages). It is possible that one of the plugins you've installed comes with its own perspective that does that. Try switching to Resource or Java perspective.

Comment: Thanks, it was not the perspectives after all. It was "Ant development" capability was disabled.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexCohn! This is the exact same problem I had, and your mention of Ant Development is what led me to the solution!