# Missing Builders option in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, build, build-automation

I want to integrate an Ant script with the Java build process in Eclipse. I don't find the option to configure builders under Project > Properties. Screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVOOF.jpg). I am able to access the Ant view but unable to access the Ant Builder from this view as well.

My Eclipse version is 3.5.2 (Galileo). I have GWT/GAE plugins installed.

Any ideas on why Builders are not available in my installation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548530/builders-page-disappeared-from-eclipse-project-properties), Ant Development needs to be checked in Window - Preferences - General - Capabilities - Advanced - Development, for the Builders option to appear under Project - Properties.